# Hide <li> element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to hide 2 links and to show only one depend on some parameter.

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
 <li id="link1"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
 <li id="link2"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link2"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
 <li id="link3"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link3"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
</ul>
```

I tried this:

```
$(".treeview-menu").find("#link1").hide()
```

and also this

```
$("#link1").hide();
```

But it doesn't work. I only succeeded with hiding all links using this part of code

```
$(".treeview-menu li").hide();
```

Comment: `$("#link1").hide();` definitely works -- assuming that the link with that `id` shown is the only element in the DOM with that `id` (which it's required to be) and that [the link is actually in the DOM when you do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: What does this give you?  `console.log($("[id=link1]"))`  If it's not 1 then that's your problem - `$("#link1").hide()` won't "work" as it will only affect the first one.

Comment: Can you check if there are more elements with same ID?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(1 == 1){
    $('li:eq(0)').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="treeview-menu">
 <li id="link1"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link1"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> 1</a>
 <li id="link2"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link2"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> 2</a>
 <li id="link3"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link3"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> 3</a>
</ul>
```

change number in eq as per requirement,

Comment: What is that `1 == 1` doing?

Comment: That is just condition, you can put any

Comment: Why is *any* condition needed here?

Comment: Because questionnaire asked it. "I want to hide 2 links and to show only one depend on some parameter.". this is just to guide him.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(".treeview-menu li:not(<the id of the li you don't want to hide>)").hide(); 
// e.g $(".treeview-menu li:not(#link2)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

One
 Two
 Three

```js
$(".treeview-menu #link1").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="treeview-menu">
 <li id="link1"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link1"><i class="fa fa-link">One</i></a>
 <li id="link2"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link2"><i class="fa fa-link">Two</i></a>
 <li id="link3"><a runat="server" href="~/Map?park=link3"><i class="fa fa-link">Three</i></a>
</ul>
```